# remote ssh execution : Single Quotes inside double quotes

Tags: ssh

All,
I have not been able to escape single quotes while writing a file to a remote node.

```
    ssh -i demo.pem -t ec2-user@10.10.10.10 'echo '\''{"watches": [{"type": "key","key": "test","handler": "neon -e 'sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh'"}]}'\''| sudo tee /etc/key.json'
```

The output I get is as follows.

```
    {"watches": [{"type": "key","key": "test","handler": "neon -e sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh"}]}
```

I would like the output to have single quotes around 'sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh'

```
    {"watches": [{"type": "key","key": "test","handler": "neon -e 'sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh'"}]}
```

'\' is not working.

Could you please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Getting multiple levels of quoting correct is troublesome and error-prone.  Consider alternative solutions, such as:

```
cat <<EOF | ssh -i demo.pem -t ec2-user@10.10.10.10 sudo tee /etc/key.json
{"watches": [{"type": "key","key": "test","handler": "neon -e 'sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh'"}]}
EOF
```

I like using `cat` because it does not require any escaping to work.  However, you can also generate the string locally using `echo` instead of `cat` as long as you escape the double quotes in your JSON expression:

```
echo "{\"watches\": [{\"type\": \"key\",\"key\": \"test\",\"handler\": \"neon -e 'sudo /opt/watch_handler.sh'\"}]}" | sudo tee /etc/key.json
```